# Javascript can't write to a file

Tags: javascript

I want the code to write datalogs to JStest.csv file after 5 clicks done by the user are completed, and I have created a CSV file call JStest in the Downloads folder. But when I run my code, it says it can't find this file. Please help !
This is the error message I got:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Downloads/JStest.csv'
Here's my code:

```
const app = require('electron').remote.app;
const fileDir = app.getPath('desktop');
const path = require("path");

var fs = require('fs');

// this will hold all the data we need
var dataLog = "";

// this will count how many clicks have occured
var clicks = 0;

var maxTrials = 5;


var iconArray = document.getElementById("iconDrawer");

// reference our start button
var startButton = document.getElementById("startBtn");

// display how many tasks a user has completed 
var counterDisplay = document.getElementById("counter");

// display the target icon to click (find the element with this HTML tag)
var indicator = document.getElementById("indicator");


// element that holds all your icons 
var parent = document.getElementById("iconDrawer");


// array of all icons (hint: use the parent var to reference its children icons)
var icons = parent.children;
var i0 = icons[0];
var i1 = icons[1];
var i2 = icons[2];
var i3 = icons[3];
var i4 = icons[4];


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TODO: Set the filepath, so you know where the .csv file is going! 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function save()
{
  // change the filepath in the writeFile() function
  fs.writeFile( path.resolve(fileDir, "/Users/lidaochang/Desktop/Downloads/JStest.csv"), dataLog, (err) => {
    if (err) alert(err);
    alert("all tasks are done");
  });
}


function randomIcon()
{
  // Generate a random number in the appropriate range 
  var iconIndex = Math.random()*4;
  iconIndex = Math.round(iconIndex);
  return iconIndex;
}

var timedClick = function()
{
  // disables the start button, so user can't press it twice 
  //startButton.onclick = function(){};

  // call randomIcon function to get random index and the matching icon
  var targetIndex = randomIcon();
  var targetIcon = icons[targetIndex];

  indicator.src = targetIcon.src;

  // start timing right here
  var startTime = performance.now();
  
  // this is where we are going to start watching for clicks on icons
  // this loop will add an onclick function to each icon
  for(var i=0; i < icons.length; i++)
  {
    icons[i].onclick = function()
    {
      // everything in here will occur when an icon is pressed

      // stop timing and record how long it took
      // calculate time elapsed 
      // record whole milliseconds 
      var endTime = performance.now();
      var timeTaken = endTime - startTime;
      timeTaken = Math.round(timeTaken);
      alert("that took " + timeTaken);

      // only 1 icon can be clicked at a time, so disable all the onclicks now! 
      // loop through all the icons and disable the function like we did with the start button
      for(var j=0; j < icons.length; j++) {
          if (j != targetIcon)
            icons[j].onclick = function(){};
      }

      // record the time and positions of the target icon and the icon the user actually pressed
      // this is to be stored in a new line in the 'dataLog' variable
      // append to the 'dataLog' variable
      var iconClicked = this.id[1]; // INCLUDE THIS
      var data = "";
      data.concat(i, " ", targetIndex, " ", iconClicked, " ", timeTaken);

      // add to the end of the 'dataLog' variable as explained above
      dataLog += data;
      // increment clicks completed
      clicks += 1;

      // update what the counterDisplay says!
      // modify the innerHTML property of counterDisplay
      // it shows the user how many clicks have currently been completed

      counterDisplay.innerHTML = clicks + " tasks out of 5 completied";

      // if maxTrials is reached, then data collection is over, so call save and reset 'clicks' and 'dataLog'
      if (clicks == maxTrials) {
          save();
          clicks = 0;
          dataLog = "";
      }
to starting the trial
      startButton.onclick = timedClick;
    }
  }
}

window.onload = function() 
{ 
  startButton.onclick = timedClick;
}
```

Comment: You're not using `path.resolve()` correctly. Take a look at the [documentation and examples](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathresolvepaths)

Comment: Do I need to change the fileDir with the file path? I tried this way but it still not work.